# transfer iTunes from Windows 7 to OSX

Tags: macos, itunes, windows

I store my music on a network location \192.168.1.6\music   I added that folder to iTunes on Windows 7.  I want to use a new Mac and I'm wondering what's the easiest/fastest way to transfer all the iTunes settings, metadata, playlists, etc from Windows to OSX?

Comment: Similar question, minus network share aspect: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-can-i-move-an-itunes-library-from-one-computer-to-another

Comment: This one also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10217/moving-my-itunes-library-file-to-a-new-machine/10233

Answer (score 1):

Just copy over the "iTunes" folder which should be located under your user's music/my music folder. If you can't find a folder there named "iTunes", you must have moved it to another location. To check, go to iTunes preferences and read the location under the "Advanced" tab.

Using any means wether it be network file transfer or using a USB Drive, move the "iTunes" folder to the "Music" folder in your mac's user account